# How To Set Custom mainChar.png In Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, png

I have a question,

How do i set a custom mainChar.png? I get this error whenever i load an example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/Game/test.py", line 265, in <module>
    intro()
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/Game/test.py", line 170, in intro
    guySprite = MainGuy(screen)
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/Game/test.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load("mainChar.png")
error: Couldn't open mainChar.png
```

How do i set my own png as mainChar.png?

Comment: maybe file is broken or file is in different folder. Or you have PyGame without PNG support.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely that there's not such a file in your script's directory. Maybe it's there and it has a different name - lowercase and uppercase matter, so check that.